# Single Massive VM or multiple VMs for Docker Containers

Tags: virtual-machine, docker

If you need to run Docker Containers for various databases and applications, is it better to:

- Run a single massive VM with a lot of memory/cpu allocated to it, or
- Run separate VMs for each application/database?

If it makes a difference, I'm using VMWare ESX.

Answer (score 0):

Different VMs. One misbehaving application would take your entire stack down, and you wouldn't want that. Separate them in a logical way and you'll be thankful you did.

Comment: But if they're in different Docker containers, how could they possibly interfere with one another?

Comment: ... http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/06/19/docker_security/